# Crystal Reports: Using Business Objects xi Datasource

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I'm a total Crystal Reports/Business Objects newbie...

I've been tasked with going through 100 or so Crystal Reports to determine which reports are using an 'embedded' connection string vs. one supplied by the BOXi server.

I've installed Crystal Reports and accessed a sampling of the reports, but haven't been able to locate any references to a Repository based connection string/datasource.

Can anyone point me towards where this configuration is managed?

Thanks!
Richard

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already tried this or even if it's too basic for you, but it's been 24 hours, so here's my 2 cents:

To see the data source of each report, open them up and go to the Database at menu at top.  There, you'll want to browse through the "Database Expert", "Set Datasource Location", and "Show SQL Query" options.  Look at the properties of each data source.

You may also want to make a practice report pulling data from your sources of interest.  That can help you get used to CR.

Comment: Hey PowerUser -- thanks for the input!

I have looked at the various options in the Database menu and I'm able to view the datasource for each individual report.

I was given the impression that the majority of the reports were leveraging a connection that was set up in the Business Objects repository, but to me, they all look like they contain embedded connection information.

Have you ever set up a Crystal Report to use a datasource that was defined in the Business Objects repository?

Again - thanks for your response!
Richard

Comment: Sorry.  I have the luxury of first passing the data from our SQL Server into an MS Access file before CR picks it up.  This way, I can SQL it to my heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

when you deploy the report to BO, you use the CMC (central management console) to set the database connection information.  it is here that you will find the answer to your connection-string question.